# Images are not showing up in "Uploaded to this post"

Tags: images, uploads, media-library

I had to delete all my files of web site for some reasons.

Then I've restored the files back to host.

But the problem is that;

Firstly, I uploaded all the images (about 4000) to upload folder via FTP. Then I realised that images are not showing up in media library. Than I used some plugins such as, Add from Server, Media Tools, but they coludnt operate all the files. I dont know why.

Then I deleted all the files again and uploaded via Wordpress Library -> Add new. After uploading all images they showed up in media library BUT they are not attached to "Uploaded to this post" of posts.

If anyone knows the solution, could you please help me about this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When you upload an image within the `post edit` screen, the image gets the `parent id` that of the `post id` you are editing. In this case if you check the `Media Library` screen, you will see the post mentioned under `Uploaded To` column against that image.

On the other hand if you directly upload an image from `Media Library` screen, then there will be no post mentioned against that image. Rather you will see `Unattached` under `Uploaded To` column for that image.

You can use the `Attach` link against that image and select the post you want to attach that image to. After that if you check in the `edit post` screen, you will see the image on selecting `Uploaded to this post` option.

Comment: Since you have a lot of images, [Attachments](http://wordpress.org/plugins/attachments/) plugin may be helpful to you but I have never tried this.